# Where to find unfinished loadings from terminal?

Tags: linux, temporary-files

So recently I tried to load AOSP directory to my machine using repo, but it was hell of a big one, so I decided to stop load by closing terminal in middle of it. Problem is, this files is already like 15Gb, and now they are somewhere in folder. Question is how do I find them and delete? I tried cleaning temp files, but they are not there, git folder is empty too. What should I do?

Comment: There's already a generic answer. If you post the exact command(s) you used then maybe a more specific answer will appear. You can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `du` (**d**isk **u**sage) to find big directories on your machine.

From `man du`:

```
       du - estimate file space usage

SYNOPSIS
       du [OPTION]... [FILE]...
       du [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
```

#### Example:

```
-$ du -d 1 -h 2&>/dev/null | sort -h                                                                                                                                                                          1 ↵
0       ./dev
0       ./proc
0       ./sys
4,0K    ./mnt
4,0K    ./opt
4,0K    ./root
4,0K    ./srv
8,0K    ./media
16K     ./lost+found
44K     ./tmp
9,5M    ./etc
73M     ./run
112M    ./boot
1,4G    ./snap
2,7G    ./var
3,5G    ./usr
25G     ./home
36G     .
```

You then simply traverse thru the directory structure, running the above command to get a clue where the missing files are.

##### Explanation

- `du` will show you the storage usage of the current directory and its subdirectories
- with `-d 1` we will limit the directory depth to one that `du` only shows the contents of the current directory
- `-h` displays the data in human readable format: `25G` instead of `25301814`
- `2&>/dev/null` will discard any error (e.g. permission denied) to `/dev/null`. Note that in my example directories for which you didn't have the permissions to acces them are shown with `0` as size.
- `sort -h` sorts the data according to the size in human readable format

#### ncdu

[ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) is a NCurses based disk usage analyzer. You can navigate it with the arrow keys and find big files and folders very fast. Personally I prefer it over plain `du` in most situations.

[image: ncdu]